# Is binding to a started local service required?

Tags: android, service

I want to use a started (foreground) service to manage a network connection that should persist when the user leaves the application for a short time, and that the user should be aware of (so he can return to the app and maybe disconnect). This service will only ever be used locally by activities in the same process.

Maybe it's just because I am new to Android, but I find it unnecessarily difficult to bind to this service in every activity that uses it - in particular, the asynchronous nature of binding, which only really seems to be necessary for accessing services in a different process. Is there any indication against just accessing the started service through a static variable instead?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm understanding your question wrong, but there is no need to bind to the started `Service` from every `Activity`. Instead, you could simply *start* the `Service` from wherever you need to interact with it. This calls the `onStartCommand()` if the `Service` is already started. You could include an extra with the `Intent` that starts the `Service` to distinguish between the first start and subsequent ones.

Of course - this addresses the use case where you do not want to have a client-server mode of interaction between your activities and the `Service` - that scenario requires binding and if you really need binding, then you need to bind from every component that needs to be served by the `Service`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure yet how to best interact with the service - that is part of the point why I am asking. However, I thought binding would make sense because the activities need to interact with the network connection - sending messages and being informed of events like chat messages. I guess the service could accept messages to send in an intent in onStartCommand instead, and inform the application at large about events by using broadcasts, but is that a better solution?

Comment: Well, I've used both approaches that you mention: 1) If the communication between `Activity` and `Service` is infrequent and sparse, it is okay to use a started Service and then in `onStartCommand()`, detect whether this was a first start or a subsequent "command". You can then communicate back to the `Activity` through broadcasts. I used this approach in a case where there were just three commands that the `Activity` could possibly issue to the `Service`; and the "return value" was a simple String or at most two values (a String and an int)....

Comment: ... 2) If there is lot of communication and you need to pass around objects, then it makes sense to use the binding approach. Even then, in most of the cases this doesn't mean you need to duplicate the binding and unbinding code in all your activities. For example, you could define a base `Activity` class that binds to the Service in its `onResume()` and unbinds in `onPause()`. You could then have all your activities inherit from this base `Activity`.

Comment: The interaction is a bit more complicated in my case since the service would e.g. hold the list of users and of recent chat messages, as well as other things an activity would want to query for display, so I still think that directly calling functions is the way to go. Which leads me back to my original question: What is the actual advantage of using binding for that, as opposed to just grabbing the service instance or related object from a static variable, which contains null if the service is not running?

Comment: How would you grab a `Service` instance? The constructor isn't much use; the `startService()` method doesn't return the `Service` instance, it just returns the `ComponentName`. OTOH, `bindService()` gives you access to the `Service` instance (or your own defined interface) through `ServiceConnection`. Even if you used a one-time binding to get this instance & stored it in a static variable; you still need to remember  binds are reference-counted. You can only unbind and MUST unbind as many times as you bind. This means you'd need to worry about where to unbind - which is a headache.

Comment: I would store the service (or my connection object) in a public static field of my Service class when the service is started, and set it to null when the service is stopped. Accessing it would be completely unrelated to binding.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14276/discussion-between-medo42-and-curioustechizen) (Ooooh, shiny new feature :P)

Comment: @Medo42 do you have any updates on any possible issues with the approach you outlined? I am trying the same thing and sometimes getting the static variable as null....